# In Ada, why are my attempts to open a file for writing failing?

Tags: file-io, ada

When I attempt to open a file to write to I get an Ada.IO_Exceptions.Name_Error.

The file name is "C:\CC_TEST_LOG.TXT". This file does not exist.

This is on Windows XP on an NTFS partition. The user has permissions to create and write to the directory.
The filename is well under the WIN32 max path length.

```
 name_2 : String := "C:\CC_TEST_LOG.TXT"
 if name_2'last > name_2'first then
    begin
       Ada.Text_IO.Create(file, Ada.Text_IO.Out_File, name_2);
       Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line(
          "CC_Test_Utils: LogFile: ERROR: Open, File "
          & name_2);
       return;
    exception
       when The_Error : others =>
          Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line(
             "CC_Test_Utils: LogFile: ERROR: Open Failed; "
              & Ada.Exceptions.Exception_Name(The_Error)
              & ", File " & name_2);
    end;
 end if;
```

Comment: I'm being able to create and open (or override) that text file with the code posted in a virtualized XP. The only thing I can think about is that in your case the file already existed and the user running that code doesn't have the correct privileges to access or modify it. Which one is the exception thrown in your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head:

- At the time `Create` is called, `file` isn't already associated with another open file is it?
- What compiler are you using? Gnat is mingw-based, and might not like the windows "C:\" designator. Try taking that part out and see if it creates the file (somewhere).
- As Xandy mentioned, the file might already be opened by another program. That `Create` call requires exclusive access to the file.

As an aside, what is the point of that Put_Line right after the `Create`? Is *successfully* opening the file also an error for some reason? It seems like it could perhaps be misleading, making one think the program failed to open the file when it actually succeeded.