# Why are my attempts to open a file using open for writing failing?

Tags: file-io, ada

When I attempt to open a file to write, I get an error: `Ada.IO_Exceptions.Name_Error`. The procedure call is `Ada.Text_IO.Open`; the file name is `C:\CC_TEST_LOG.TXT`. This file does not exist.

This is on Windows XP on an NTFS partition. The user has permissions to create and write to the directory.
The filename is well under the WIN32 max path length.

```
 name_2 : String := "C:\CC_TEST_LOG.TXT"
 if name_2'last > name_2'first then
    begin
       Ada.Text_IO.Open(file, Ada.Text_IO.Out_File, name_2);
       Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line(
          "CC_Test_Utils: LogFile: ERROR: Open, File "
          & name_2);
       return;
    exception
       when The_Error : others =>
          Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line(
             "CC_Test_Utils: LogFile: ERROR: Open Failed; "
              & Ada.Exceptions.Exception_Name(The_Error)
              & ", File " & name_2);
    end;
 end if;
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but that initial if-test (name_2'last > name_2'first) seems to be checking just that the filename isn't empty. If that's its only purpose, then just do:

   if name_2 /= "" then
      ...

Comment: Marc C: Yes that test could be improved to name_2'Length /= 0. I'm assuming that would be faster than the equality test; but I will need to profile. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the "file does not exist," you should [`Create`](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-8-2.html) it first, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bada%5D%20Ada.Text_IO.Create). Note that "For text input-output, the procedures `Create`, `Open`, and `Reset` have additional effects described in subclause [A.10.2](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-10-2.html)."

If this is related to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413549), it may help to provide more details.

Comment: This, was the original problem I was having. I found no answers to it on the web, or in the books. So I asked it here for others reference.